# Using Apple earbud in-line remote functions on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, desktop-computer, headphones

Is it possible to use the in-line remote of Apple-compatible headphones on a PC running Windows 8?
If this is possible, what hardware/drivers are necessary?

It would seem that this is significantly more difficult than I initially anticipated. Some googling indicates that you can't even get *any* microphone to work on a MacBook running Windows, nevermind a headphone + mic combo or the volume controls.

Comment: How do you plan on using them exactly? What operating system are you talking about? Please choose proper tags.

Comment: @slhck, added windows 8 tag to reflect OS usage. I intend to use them for listening to music, Skype, volume control, play/pause/next track functionality